# display my table with vertical headers from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert

How do I take the results from a MySQL SELECT query and display it vertically?

Instead of:

```
Name|Age|Question

andrew|25|How are you
```

I want:

```
Name| andrew

Age| 25

Question| How are you
```

I can't do in PHP - `syntax error`???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here are some clues for you:

1. Use PDO or mysqli to fetch your data

   ```
   SELECT * FROM mytable
   ```
2. Use a foreach loop:

   ```
   foreach ($item as $key => value){
       //Change this part as you wish
       echo $key."|".$value."<br>";
   }
   ```
3. Use css to "make it vertical"

Comment: Use PDO or mysqli to fetch your data